# fail to upload pdf document on chrome using view button

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm trying to view files (i.e: excel sheets/pdf/images) on browser that are stored in database.  I already wrote a code for downloading the files from the database and it is working but I want to display it in the browser.

Here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id = intval($_GET['id']);

// Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
if($id <= 0) {
    die('The ID is invalid!');
}
else {
    // Connect to the database
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "crystalwnj");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Fetch the file information
    $query = "
        SELECT `mime`, `name`, `size`, `data`
        FROM `file`
        WHERE `id` = {$id}";
    $result = $con->query($query);

    if($result) {
        // Make sure the result is valid
        if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        // Get the row
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            // Print headers


            $file=$row['data'];
            $filename=$row['name'];
            header("Cache-Control: maxage=1");
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $filename. '"');
            header("Content-Description: File Tranfer");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
            header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

            // Print data
            readfile($row['name']);

        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
        }

        // Free the mysqli resources
        @mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$con->error}</pre>";
    }
    @mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: if you have more than one row `if($result->num_rows == 1)` will fail you. You can use either `if($result->num_rows >= 1)` or `if($result->num_rows >0)` - You also need a `while` loop for `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: I removed  if($result->num_rows == 1) form my code now..I am going to edit code in this post .Please look into it once.